# Was the ionosphere plotline motivated by real-world considerations?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, black-lightning-2018

In the fourth season, Jen is replaced by an evil double that hijacked her DNA and memories in order to pretend that it was actually her. Rather than having the same person play both characters, as would seem logical from the premise, the double is played by a different person.

Jen eventually returns in the final episode, played by her original actor. Out-of-universe, was this plotline motivated by availability or other real-world issues with the actor playing Jen, or was it an intentional artistic decision? Either direct evidence (e.g. from an interview) or indirect evidence (e.g. her actor was filming another show at the same time) would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two different Q&A accounts [Digital Spy](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/ustv/a35583073/black-lightning-china-anne-mcclain-jennifer-exit/) and [Alberquerque Journal](https://www.abqjournal.com/2390057/shifting-roles-2.html) that covered China Anne McClain decision to leave the show at the end of season 4. This decision seems to have been made before the show's cancellation.

> The Jennifer Pierce actress revealed shortly after the series was confirmed to be ending that she had already taken the decision to quit during the fourth and final season regardless.

It seems likely that the introduction of a different actor, [Laura Kariuki](https://arrow.fandom.com/wiki/Laura_Kariuki), to play the same character role was intended to accustom the audience to a shift that would have been required to retain the character into Season 5 and beyond. Potentially the return of China Anne McClain in the final episode is only because the series had been cancelled, but I can't find an explicit confirmation of this.

> McClain decided before the beginning of this, the fourth and final season, to leave the series, and the show wrote in a transition, where Jennifer’s body had to be reconstituted after an explosion.